# Force Wordpress Server IP to redirect to domain name

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp

I configured a Wordpress site in LAMP (only one site under /var/www/), including an ssl certificate, the domain works fine, with no cert issues,however, if i reach the website using its public IP I get an error for the cert:

```
Your connection is not private
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

which makes sense, since the cert is generated for the domain name and not the IP. I tried adding the following rule using my public IP and domain name as suggested in other posts to force a redirect from IP to domain name within the .htaccess file but it did not help:

```
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.xx.xx.xxx$ [OR]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also tried the same on two virtual host files one on port 80 and 443:

```
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xxx$ [OR]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Is the Apache rewrite module on, and have you tried restarting the apache server yet? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirect-ip-address-to-domain-name-apache?answer=19074

Comment: wouldn't you just want to redirect to https right away?

Comment: Yes rewrite engine module is already enabled:  sudo a2enmod rewrite, and apache was restarted.
@OlafKock I believe it is, going to the domain name shows HTTPS fine, but when going by ip address i get the connection is not secure

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, I used the following re-write condition in my htaccess file adding the IP :xx.xx..., and restarted apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I hope this helps future people who experience the same issue.